# Ajax not loading without refreshing the page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

This following ajax code not working without refresh can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong, thanks

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    fetch_data();
    function fetch_data(){
        var action = "fetch";
        $.ajax({
            url:"action.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{action:action},
            success:function(data) {
                $('#image_data').html(data);
            }
        })
```

Comment: place your function definition outside `document.ready`

Comment: @GuruprasadRao i did now ajax not working

Comment: Check if you have any console errors? Check network tab in browser to see `ajax` request is fired..

Comment: First you need to share an entire portion of code, your function like here is not ended so cannot work !

Comment: you can load the ajax one time because when you will refresh the page jquery will call the function after that  jquery will not call the function without any event .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Place function outside `$(document).ready(function)`, because function must be loaded before all page load**

> You can run function while click on "Run Function" button

```
<button id="run_function">Run function</button>

$(document).ready(function(){

    fetch_data();

    /* Script for run function on button click */
    $('#run_function').click(function() { fetch_data(); return false; });
});

function fetch_data()
{
    var action = "fetch";
    $.ajax({
        url:"action.php",
        method:"POST",
        data:{action:action},
        success:function(data)
        {
            $('#image_data').html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help now ajax working without refresh but  for the second time only first time when I am calling through <input type="button" onClick="fetch_data()" value="Run Function"> it's not working but the second time it's calling

Comment: @NithishPK  check updated answer i have shown, how can you run function on click button ...

Comment: @NithishPK Welcome ... :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code will only run once per page load unless you call it via some other method.  Here is a script that will run it each time you press the button.  Also, make sure you have jquery installed.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="button" onClick="fetch_data()" value="Run Function">

<script>

function fetch_data(){

  var action = "fetch";

    $.ajax({
    url:"action.php",
    method:"POST",
    data:{action:action},
    success:function(data)
    {
     $('#image_data').html(data);
    }
});

$(document).ready(function(){

fetch_data();


});


</script>
```

Comment: thanks for the help now ajax working without refresh but for the second time only first time when I am calling through <input type="button" onClick="fetch_data()" value="Run Function"> it's not working but the second time it's calling

Comment: @Nithish P K  Updated my answer..  I added the function in the jquery ready function.  That way it runs on load, and then when you press the button.. Please mark as accepted answer if it works for you!  Cheers